# Возникает ошибка «System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException»?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
char[] glas1 = { 'и', 'о', 'у', 'е', 'а', 'ї' };

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Абракадабра");

for (int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < glas1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (builder[i] == glas1[i])
        {
            builder.Insert((int)builder[i], "-");
        }

    }
}

string word = builder.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, ну про `glas1[j]` вам уже написали. Теперь глянем на следующую строчку:

```
builder.Insert((int)builder[i], "-");
```

Что здесь вообще происходит? Я так понимаю, вы хотите заменить гласные на тире. Ну так для замены нужно использовать метод `Replace`.

Вы же пытаетесь вставить символ в `builder` на определённое место. В качестве индекса места вставки вы почему-то берёте не `i`, как было бы логично, а код символа (то есть той самой гласной). Понятно, что код символа довольно велик и в качестве индекса далеко выходит за рамки того списка, который находится в `builder`. И выходит ошибка индексации.

Но даже если вы исправите индекс вставки на `i`, то да, тогда вы будете вставлять символы, и `builder` будет увеличиваться, гласная будет съезжать на следующую позицию, там вы опять будете вставлять символ в позицию этой гласной, и так пока память у программы не кончится.

Так что видимо всё же вам нужен `Replace`, а не `Insert`, тогда хоть что-то путное на выходе получится.

Answer (score 0):

В строке `Абракадабра` - 11 символов, в массиве `glas1`- 6.

Теперь спросите себя, что будет происходить с `glas1` на строке

```
if (builder[i] == glas1[i])
```

когда `i` будет больше 5?

Может там должно быть `glas1[j]`?

Comment: Спасибо, что-то недоглядел. Но когда поменял, всё равно та же ошибка :((

Comment: Знаете, я вам не верю.

Comment: у вас будет ошибка уже на строке `builder.Insert((int)builder[i], "-");` .